# undefined method `create' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, sunspot-solr

I made a rails-api project.. developed it on windows .. and all the request response work right there.. 
As soon as I took it to linux server... I get this error :

```
undefined method `create' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class
```

I get this error in the model class :

```
class TableOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "table_one"
  has_many :table_twos, foreign_key: "id"

  #contains searchable block for sunspot-solr
end
```

The API that I am hitting makes no db queries. Only solr requests. 
Any help ?

**UPDATE 1**

This is table one :

```
class TableOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "table_one"
  has_many :table_twos, foreign_key: "two_id"
  searchable do
    text :title, :stored => true
    integer :status, :stored => true
    string :id, :multiple => true, :stored => true do
      table_twos.map(&:two_id)
    end
  end
end
```

This is my table two :

```
class TableTwo< ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "table_two"
  belongs_to :table_one
end
```

And to search (using sunspot solr) I am using the following in my controller :

```
@search= TableOne.search do
        fulltext "go"
        all_of do 
            with(:status,1)
            without(:id,nil)
        end
        paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 5
    end
    @search.hits.each do |hit|
        puts hit.stored(:title)
        puts hit.stored(:id)[0]}
    end
```

**UPDATE 2**
This is the error :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class):
 app/models/table_one.rb:2:in `<class:TableOne>'
 app/models/table_one.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 app/controllers/search_controller.rb:55:in `send_response'
 app/controllers/search_controller.rb:40:in `populate_bean'
```

On windows I got no such error.

Comment: Can you add the line of the request?

Comment: please check update 1.. thanks

Comment: There is not any `create` method called on your code..Can you add the whole error stack?

Comment: Please check update 2...

Comment: Did you try without renaming tables?

Comment: I am using an existing database ... not something I have created via the models in rails...that's why the `self.table_name = ".."` part..

Comment: Ok. In that case, you need to be sur that every `_` is changed by the first  letter of the next word **in capital**. Can you add `search_controller.rb` method `send_response`? The problem starts at line 55.

Comment: you mean make it `has_many : TableTwos` ??

Comment: Nop. This won't ever work for sur. Can you add your `send_response` method?

Comment: You did well on your code but I just wanted to add some details.

Comment: send_response just has the `@search...` part...and `puts` the result .. as shown in the block of code above

Comment: anyway ... I re-did everything ... deleted the project .. took the project again from windows to linux... re bundled the gems etc .. and it worked fine... No idea what the problem was... Thanks a ton for all your help :)

Comment: Ok great ! Nobody will know the solution.